# "Unable to connect to data source" while using DolphinDB ODBC to connect mssql

Tags: plugins, odbc, dolphindb

I have installed mssql server2017, unixODBC and tdsodbc on ubuntu 18. After configuring the DSN, I execute this code:

```
isql -v testjob SA Password1
```

It shows me an correct connection.

Then I load the ODBC plugin in DolphinDB GUI:

```
loadPlugin("/home/xhtang/dolphindb/server/plugins/odbc/PluginODBC.txt")
```

The plugin has been loaded successfully.

I connect the mssql server:

```
use odbc
conn = connect("Dsn=testjob")
```

But an error comes:

```
error connecting to [D]: odbc/src/nanodbc.cpp:1051: 0800: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to 
connect to data source
```

I have tried to connect by other means, but still failed. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that the ODBC DSN in the connect statement in the DolphinDB GUI is not set correctly. You can try the following connection methods:

```py
conn = odbc::connect("DSN=testjob;Uid=SA;Pwd=Password1;")
```